Handling File Upload Button Relocation in Selenium Java During Automation Execution
Our web application faces an issue during automation testing where the File Upload button sometimes changes its location on the page.
By default, the button is supposed to be centered, but during some automation test runs, it unexpectedly shifts to either the right or left corners of the screen. This results in an ElementNotFoundException in Selenium Java, as the element is no longer at its expected position.
//code to click file upload button
Utilities.wait(2);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Utilities.executorClick(uploadPage.uploadFile, driver);
Utilities.wait(2);

//wait function
public static void wait(int wait) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
         new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Loading']"))));`
    }catch(Exception e) {
        
    }
   Thread.sleep(wait * 1000);
}

//executorClick function
 public static void executorClick(WebElement webElement, WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
}

This issue occurs intermittently and seems to be related to the layout or rendering changes during the automation process. It affects the consistency and reliability of our test cases, particularly when interacting with this dynamic element.
We are looking for an effective way to handle this scenario in Selenium to ensure our test doesn’t fail due to this unexpected element displacement. Is there a method or best practice in Selenium Java to identify and interact with elements that may change location dynamically?
Any insights on handling this type of behavior would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
